# Bounce animation on a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I would like to have a bounce animation on a view controller.

I know how to do this on a CollectionView but not a ViewController. I know that TableViews do this automatically.

It should be the view so for example:

```
collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT**: I have added a scroll view, but for some reason the view won't scroll. Here is the image: [image]

Comment: I assume you mean the pull and bounce back on release? If so, you'd probably need to start with a `UIScrollView`

Comment: yes that is what I mean. Ok I have a scroll view what do I do now?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on scroll views. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, so you'll have to do some digging.

Comment: What I am looking for is: I have a view with a label on it and I would like the label to have that vertical bounce effect as well as have the search bar that is at the top go away and come back when you slide the screen down

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: For some reason it won't scroll I am not sure why?